# Javascript timer to use multiple times in a page

Tags: javascript, timer

I have this Javascript count down timer that works perfectly. Only problem is i can use it for only one time in one page. I want to use it multiple times.

I think script use `id ="timer"` that is why i am not able to use it multiple times.

Below  is the JS code:

```
<script>
var startTime = 60; //in Minutes
var doneClass = "done"; //optional styling applied to text when timer is done
var space = '       ';

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  var intervalLoop = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = "00" + space + minutes + space + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
      document.querySelector("#timer").classList.add(doneClass);
      clearInterval(intervalLoop);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = now.getHours();
  var setMinutes = 60 * (startTime - now.getMinutes() - (now.getSeconds() / 100)),
    display = document.querySelector("#timer");

  startTimer(setMinutes, display);
};
</script>
```

Comment: So what is your coding issue? A good start is to put the global variables into functions. Consider using a constructor to create instances, or closures to keep variables "private" per call to the timer.

Comment: Yep, wrap timer related stuff in function - thats the solution. make it like a prototype, so you could make instances of it

Comment: @RobG Judging from his code and his question, I'm not sure OP is at this coding level right now.

Comment: @RobG I am beginner in Javascript so not completely aware of the variables in function or outside function. Could you please tweak the code to show what could work ?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `intervalLoop` outside of the `startTimer` function, it'll be available globally.

```
var intervalLoop = null

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  intervalLoop = setInterval(function() { .... }
})


function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(intervalLoop) // Also available here!
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function(){ Your function }, 1000);
```

Here `1000` means `timer 1 sec`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this could be helpful:

Timer object declaration

```js
var timerObject = function(){
 this.startTime = 60; //in Minutes
 this.doneClass = "done"; //optional styling applied to text when timer is done
 this.space = '       ';

  return this;
};

timerObject.prototype.startTimer = function(duration, display) {
  var me = this, 
    timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  var intervalLoop = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = "00" + me.space + minutes + me.space + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
      // not sure about this part, because of selectors
      document.querySelector("#timer").classList.add(me.doneClass);
      clearInterval(intervalLoop);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Use it like

```
var t1 = new timerObject();
var t2 = new timerObject();
t1.startTimer(a,b);
t2.startTimer(a,b);
```

JS Fiddle example:

*UPD1 commented part so the the timer could be stopped*

https://jsfiddle.net/9fjwsath/1/

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me how will var t1 and t2 work.

Currently in HTML i just use `<span id = "timer">`. How will this work?

Comment: @SahibjotSingh oh, so you want to use it like, applying to same html element?

Comment: If this is how it could work. That would be great. I have no problem in changing the id or using the classes. But i need to use them in some HTML element.

Comment: @SahibjotSingh I tought you want to use this many times at many places on your page. Addeed link to example

Comment: thanks for your changes. It works in fiddle but in my code it doesn't seem to work as expected. In fiddle as well the timer should reduce but it is incremented. :(

Comment: @SahibjotSingh could you please show your html part, I mean, the one you apllying timer for?

Comment: @Danish this is html part `<p><span id="timer">00 00 00</span></p>`

Comment: @SahibjotSingh hi! so you want to restart it or what? I mean, how it suppose to behave?